# Angular Pills with dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to create pills in angular with a dropdown.
I have achieved this but the problem is that only the span or a is clickable and not the rest of the pill.
However if i click the pill it still hightlights the pill but does not do the task it has to do when i click it. How can i achieve that the full span is clickable and not only the text.

Below is my code:

```
<div data-tabset="" type="pills">
        <div style="height: 80px" data-tab="" data-active="item.active" data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-if="(item.Processes.length >= 1)">
            <div data-tab-heading="">

                <span style="height: 80px" class="dropdown" ng-if="(item.Processes.length > 1)">
                    <span class="dropdown-toggle">
                        {{item.Name}}
                    </span>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="proc in item.Processes">
                            <a dropdown-toggle ng-click="Function2(item.ID,proc.UniqueID)">{{proc.Description}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a dropdown-toggle ng-click="Function1(item.ID,-1)">all</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
                <span style="height: 80px" ng-if="(item.Processes.length == 1)" ng-click="Function1(item.ID,item.proc.UniqueID)">{{item.Name}}</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Put the ng-click on the <li> tag?

Comment: The Problem is in the Pill. In the li (dropdown) it works but also here it only dropdowns when i click on the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding a function on all spans that checks what value is selected and deselects all and selects that one. It is not that the click works now but at least not the wrong one is selected now.

Html:

```
 <div data-tabset="" type="pills">
        <div data-ng-if="(subsidiaries.length == 0)"><h2>U heeft geen werkmaatschappijen om te tonen</h2></div>
        <div style="height: 80px" data-tab="" data-active="sub.active" data-ng-repeat="sub in subsidiaries" data-ng-click="setPillSelected()" data-ng-if="(sub.Processes.length >= 1)">
            <div data-tab-heading="">

                <span style="height: 80px" class="dropdown" dropdown ng-if="(sub.Processes.length > 1)">
                    <span class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
                        {{sub.Name}}
                    </span>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="proc in sub.Processes">
                            <a ng-click="generateFunnelData(sub.SubsidiaryID,proc.SubsidiaryProcessID, true)">{{proc.Description}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a ng-click="generateFunnelData(sub.SubsidiaryID,-1, true)">alles</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
                <span style="height: 80px" ng-if="(sub.Processes.length == 1)" ng-click="generateFunnelData(sub.SubsidiaryID,sub.proc.SubsidiaryProcessID, true)">{{sub.Name}}</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript side:

```
setPillSelected: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.$.subsidiaries.forEach(function(subsidiary) {
        if (subsidiary.SubsidiaryID == self.$.subsidiary.SubsidiaryID) {
            subsidiary.active = true;
        } else {
            subsidiary.active = false;
        }
    });


},
```

i hope it can help other people